# how to get call back each time when rootviewcontroller of UIWindow changes

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to iOS development. I am stuck in a problem where my use case is to get callback each time when the rootviewcontroller of UIWindow changes. I know there is a rootviewcontroller.tansiondelegate delegate property in rootviewcontroller but i am unable to get callback after using this delegate.

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: i want to access the currently visible view controller each time when a new view controller is presented.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `KVO` to observe the change of property. like:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"rootViewController" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:@"rootViewControllerChange"];
```

and when the rootViewController is changed, will call method:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([(__bridge NSString *)context isEqualToString:@"rootViewControllerChange"] ) {
        // code what you want to do...
    }
}
```

NOTE:

Don't forget to remove this observer when the instance of [self class] dealloc.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"rootViewController" context:@"rootViewControllerChange"];
```

#### if it is not working:

There is a more stupid method：☔️

you can use NSNotificationCenter, when you present a controller, you can

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"PushNotificationPresentedController" object:nil userInfo:nil];
```

and addObserver to receive this Notification where you want to callback:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didPresentedController) name:@"PushNotificationPresentedController" object:nil];
```

> （if i have another better method, i will update my answer.）

Comment: it is not working. Are you sure the rootviewcontroller is KVO compliant?

Comment: that will surely work. But in my use case i do not know the view controller in advance. so i have to play with rootview controller only. you can refer the link posted in my answer for more fun on this topic

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. I used method swizzling for this. Very useful concept. 
Please refer [this](http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/) for method swizzling technique.
Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36124902/trigger-an-event-method-when-uiwindow-rootviewcontroller-changes-swift) for similar question.